# How to Merge Purchase Requisitions OpenERP 7 [ bug ? ]

Tags: odoo

I have 3 questions to sort out regarding OpenERP Purchase flow.

(1.) can we merge multiple Purchase Requisitions ?
(because its difficult to manager to send one by one sometimes.)
ex : in XYZ company x division needs 2 pens,y division needs 3 pens, z division needs 2 pens.then its easier to manager to get all Purchase Requisitions from those divisions and merge it and send to supplier or call for quotation for 7 pens in onetime.

(2.) in exist purchase module its give rights to **user** to create Purchase Requisitions and send those to suppliers & call quotations & make PO also.its commonly not used in here.user create a Purchase Requisitions and then Manager approve them and send to suppliers or call quotations.in OpenERP ver 7 how to do that ?

(3.) in OpenERP ver 7 where i can find a virtual locations option & inventory requisition ?